# Why isn't there separate CapsLock layer for num-keys in Windows?

Tags: windows, keyboard-layout

The Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator can create 3 и 4 layers `AltGr` and `AltGr`+`Shift` for every letter-keys (and num-keys above), but `CapsLock` layer works only for letter-keys.

Using The microsoft keyboard layout creator, only for letter-keys, I can create:
`c` = `c`
`Shift` + `c` = `C`
`AltGr` + `c` = `©`
`AltGr` +`Shift`+ `c` = `¢`
`CapsLock`, `c` = `€`
`CapsLock`, `Shift` + `c` = `‽`

So:

1) Why isn't there CapsLock layer for num-key, and always
`numkey = CapsLock, numkey`?

(while through The Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator I can make `letter ≠ CapsLock, letter`)

2) Is there a way to disable NumPad Alt-codes for some keyboard layout?

P.S. I want to make:
`CapsLock`, `7` = ₇
`CapsLock`, `Shift` + `7` = ⁷

and etc. (`AltGr` + `num-keys` already get their value)

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Have you used AutoHotKey or AutoIt?

Comment: I use “the microsoft keyboard layout creator”. I am asking about keyboard layouts.

Comment: MS KB Layout is only meant to map keys with [scancode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scancode), scancode only represent existing keys on keyboard. Since superscript 7 & subscript 7 doesn't exist in standard keyboard layout, you can't do that. You'll want AutoHotKey/AutoIt instead, where you send keypresses/characters instead of just calling a particular scancode

Comment: question is updated. I can do `CapsLock`, `q` = ₇ or `AltGr` + `7` = ₇, but not `CapsLock`,  `7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution.

it's not some standard num-keys bug from a typewriter's time, when letter-keys and num-keys were distinguished.

Problem matters only for “The microsoft keyboard layout creator”. App has not been being updated since 2007, and still has had described bug: it's not correct at creating CapsLock layers (mostly with num-keys CapsLock Layers).

There is [KdbEdit](http://www.kbdedit.com), it's works awesome, and I get my `X₌₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉₀₊₋` `X⁼¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁰⁺⁻`  for `CapsLock` and `CapsLock`,`Shift` layers.